# Which PHP shell?

Tags: php, shell, read-eval-print-loop

One of the nice features of languages like Python, Ruby or LISP is the availability of an interactive shell. This goes in a Read-Eval-Print Loop and allows to quickly experiment with the language without having to write and execute scripts.

Unfortunately PHP has nothing like that out of the box, but one can [find](http://www.phpsh.org/)  some [external](http://david.acz.org/phpa/) tools [online](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/php-shell/). I found three and I'm not sure which are the relative advantages?

> Did anyone try one of those shells and can give some advice about which one to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unfortunately PHP has nothing like that out of the box

Yes, it does.  `php -a` or `php --interactive` are what you're looking for.  They're *useless* before PHP 5.3 (segfaulty promptless `<?php`-prefix-requiring *crap*), but they fixed it up pretty well... just don't do anything that will trigger a fatal error.

Oh, and if you need to include a file that tries to do use [getopt](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php), you can make it work by opening the prompt thusly:

```
php -a -- --custom -s -t -u --ff="goes here" --the=first --double-dash --is="Magic!"
```

Comment: Don't worry, it's well-hidden and poorly-advertised.

Comment: AFACT `php -a` is a REL and not a REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) shell though like node,python,ruby, ... Really annoying.

Answer (score 6):

```
php -a
```

via command line invokes the interactive shell

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Facebook's](https://github.com/facebook/phpsh) (Python based!) PHP shell to work great, I've never gotten PHP built in interactive shell to work without custom compiling.